# How to add a new activity and layout eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity, menu

I started programming for android with eclipse a few days ago
However, I am stuck now.

I would like to add a new activity, so that i can add a new screen with new layout (an info screen about the app)

It is made so that when you press a specific menu button (help) it launches the help.xml activity and shows a new screen with some new words.

This succeeded one time, but I cant manage to do this another time.

Here is the code to direct to the activity, made from the main.java:

```
  @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate (R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}


public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
switch (item.getItemId()) 
{

    case R.id.help:
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, help.class);
        startActivity(intent);


    case R.id.quit:
        System.exit(0);  
    break;
```

I dont have code in the help.java, and I have made some buttons in help.xml

The 'quit' button works fine but the help thing doesnt.
I am also very unsure where it links to, as the previous time I had to both make a help.java and a help.xml activity.

I already noted the help activity in the manifest.xml

Help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: What happens when clicking help button ?

Comment: As an aside, never use System.exit(0) unless you know what you're doing and have a good reason to.  Instead, .finish() your activity.

Comment: I should have explained that, when I click the button i get a standard white screen. I already managed to make it dark and without action bar in the manifest.xml, but it seems that it doesnt show the help.xml file with some test buttons and text.                                                           I made the system.exit command for quitting easily, does this damage the phone/app or something?

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to write break after starting new Activity. That was the issue.

Replace this code:

```
   case R.id.help:
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, help.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    case R.id.quit:
        System.exit(0);  
    break;
```

with

```
   case R.id.help:
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, help.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    break;
    case R.id.quit:
        System.exit(0);  
    break;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I Should have told that i can click help, but it only shows the standard theme. No help.xml buttons and text.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot the break, and then in your help class

public class help extends Activity
    {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.help);
    }
    }